# Can the SNP and Plaid Cymru be accurately categorized as national socialists?

Tags: united-kingdom, socialism, fascism

Can the SNP and Plaid Cymru be accurately categorized as national socialists ?

They are nationalist parties with a left wing economic and social agenda. If this is the case how can the high level of support as compared to the the BNP be explained.

Comment: I don't think Single-nucleotide polymorphism exibits any specific political leanings

Answer (score 1):

It's not simple to answer, since "National Socialism" can encompass quite a bit of ground and definitions if varying strictness/broadness. But trying to restrict to most common denominator :

- Plaid Cymru clearly is NOT Nationals Socialist **in theory** since one of its [platform planks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaid_Cymru#Platform) is:

  > To build a national community based on equal citizenship, respect for different traditions and cultures and the equal worth of all individuals, whatever their race, nationality, gender, colour, creed, sexuality, age, ability or social background;

  This clearly is opposite one of the main tenets of National Socialism as practced in Nazi Germany, which was based on ideas of racial purity and NON-equality between races and nationalities.

  Of course, theory doesn't mean practice, either at the top (e.g. USSR declared equality on paper but treated many nationalities as second class) or at the bottom (e.g. plenty of base neo-Nazi support in pro-Putin party in Russia)

Comment: Based on that description of their platform they do not appear to be a nationalist party at all, which begs the question, why would they seek independence if they are not a nationalist party.

Comment: @user1450877 - Blame the English (language, not people). The word "nationalist" has way too many definitions.

Comment: I meant that it seems very strange for a region to seek self determination when it isn't based on  some sort of racial or cultural identity.

Comment: @user1450877 - identity can be coupled with **either** disparaging **or** equalizing other nationals/ethnicities. The devil is in the details.

Comment: for sure that is the case BUT the UK government is already committed to multiculturalism. They already live in a national community that strives for those things and are full and equal members of the democratic franchise. They are dedicated to leaving a national entity that is identical to what they claim to want.

Comment: @user1450877 - well, the accent's different :) But yes, the main point of independence is local control, NOT "nationalism" in an ethnic and cultural sense, as far as Scotland is concerned

Answer (score 0):

No, as national socialism (aka nazism) is a very specific political ideology based on the ideas of Adolf Hitler. As far as I can tell Plaid Cymru is a Welsh party based on social democracy. That is a very different thing. You can't just take words out of context. Not everyone with athlete's foot is an athlete.

Comment: You need to analyze what specific planks of SNP are common and different from national socialism to make any (positive or negative) assertion

Comment: Good answer. Names are just names; otherwise the US Republican party would favour dictatorship, since they are not Democrats, and the US Democratic party would be monarchists, since they are not Republicans...

Answer (score -3):

Usually when a political party applies a label to themselves (national socialist) which clearly does not apply, and suddenly the whole population seems to believe it even though there is no real evidence for it, it is usually due to a heavy, heavy dose of propaganda and media control.  Most likely the media in your country is mainly all owned by a very small number of organizations or individuals, and through some kind of collaboration between those owners, the exact same ideas get fed to everyone through the same sources, until there are too many people repeating it (and sure they know what they are talking about it) for any of these geniuses to ever be convinced otherwise.

I live in the USA and know nothing about your political parties, but it is a similar situation here.  Only here people we have a socialist dictatorship disguised as a democracy, because our freedom of the press is undermined by a high cost of media delivery and the fact that ALL of the media is owned by 5 different companies.